# Change format from one column to two columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="blocks">
      <h2 style="text-align: center">Extra Information</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><i class="fa fa-book fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Reference it for later</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Give Feedback</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Why are annotations so important?</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>They say Annotation websites are for genius; well this is why you are here!</div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Interaction</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Information</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like Image 1
[image: Image1]

How can I make it look like image 2 but with 2 columns, because mine is all stuck with eachother:
[image: Image2]

Comment: could you make a quick draw of what you want ? it's not clear...

Comment: ok done i put what i have and what i want @Blag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't have more than 12 col by row, so your code is wrong.

Second, please, don't use the "I'll put every class and it'll work" as suggested by my fellow, Bootstrap work on a cascade way, you just have to set on the "until the smallest screen" you want.

If you want 2 col even in **`xs-`**, then just use the `col-xs-6`, no need to set the `sm- / md- / lg-`.

And last, I don't really understand what you want, this ?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="blocks">
      <h2 style="text-align: center">Extra Information</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-book fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Reference it for later</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Give Feedback</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Why are annotations so important?</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>They say Annotation websites are for genius; well this is why you are here!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Interaction</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><i class="fa  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I put them on there separate row, it messed up the colors, I just want them to be 2 columns and same size boxes.

Comment: @Serena you have 5 element, you can't put them in 2 columns without the last one being single

Comment: I know I will add another element, should I post a photo of how I want it to  look like?

Comment: @Serena the picture could be a good idea; for the color, you **have** to use the row, the color is another problem, in which way it mess-up ?

Comment: They become both dark when it should be one dark one light, I put an image of what I want above

Comment: @Serena ok so the code I put is really what you want, now you need to work on the CSS to make it look how you want. it's not bootstrap related I think (or what class are you using for this ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127960/discussion-between-serena-and-blag).

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, `.col-md-` class is used for medium screens, `.col-xs-` means extra small and `col-sm` for small screens

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="blocks">
            <h2 style="text-align: center">Extra Information</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Reference it for later
                    <br>
                    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Give Feedback
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Why are annotations so important?
                    <br>
                    <i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>They say Annotation websites are for genius; well this is why you are here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```